# Create Class diagram from Java Source code - Rational Software Architect 7

Tags: rational-rsa

Does anybody know how to create a class diagram from java source code in Rational sofware architect 7? Its supposed to be a straightforward procedure, but so far i haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about v7 specific capabilities, in v8 of RSA the simplest way to create Class Diagrams is documented here

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.viz.j2se.doc/topics/tcrjavadiagram.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below this shall be of help.
http://nsinfra.blogspot.in/2012/06/class-diagram-generation-from-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Does this link on the IBM site help you?

Reverse engineer UML diagrams by using IBM Rational Software Architect, Version 7.5 http://ibm.co/vzm15r

And this one too:

Reverse engineering UML class and sequence diagrams from Java code with IBM Rational Software Architect http://ibm.co/uueAC5